# Authorisation error with AWS API Gateway using access token

Tags: authorization, aws-api-gateway, access-token

I have followed the AWS documentation for enabling an authoriser for API access using Cognito tokens.

When I test the authoriser with the ID token within the AWS console, it works fine.
On using the access tokens and trying to access via Postman I repeatedly get and "unauthorised" error (401).

I have tried the following but to no avail

1. Disabling and enabling CORS (both combinations)
2. Using the ID token instead of the access token
3. Republishing the API after changing the auth scope params
4. Deleting and recreating the API again

When I turn off authorisation the API works fine via Postman/ Browser. When I turn it back on again the problem resurfaces.

Comment: Add more information like the request header and configurations you have used in the apigateway console.

Comment: I redid it entirely, deleted the API and and re-created it. It inexplicably worked this time. Might have been a bug or some legacy setting that wasn't getting updated. Though I have seen a few complaints about the identical problem.  Thanks a lot.